# How to make this equation to its solutions were $\frac{a}{b+c-a} ; \frac{b}{c+a-b} ; \frac{c}{a+b-c}$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $a,b,c$ be solutions of $x^3+px^2+qx+r=0$. How can we transform this equation so its solutions are $\frac{a}{b+c-a} ; \frac{b}{c+a-b} ; \frac{c}{a+b-c}$?

I know $a+b+c=-p$, $abc=r$, $ab+bc+ca=q$.

Comment: This is not right: We have $A + B + C = -p$, where $A, B, C$ are the roots of the polynomial, but the given roots are not $a, b, c$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $y=\dfrac a{b+c-a},y=\dfrac a{b+c+a-2a}=\dfrac a{-p-2a}$

Express $a$ in terms of $y,p$

As $a$ is a root of the given equation, replace the value of $a$ in the given equation and simplify

Answer (score 0):

Compute and simplify the following:

$$\frac{a}{b+c-a} + \frac{b}{c+a-b} + \frac{c}{a+b-c}$$
$$\frac{a}{b+c-a}\frac{b}{c+a-b} + \frac{b}{c+a-b}\frac{c}{a+b-c} + \frac{c}{a+b-c}\frac{a}{b+c-a}$$
$$\frac{a}{b+c-a} \frac{b}{c+a-b} \frac{c}{a+b-c}$$

This step takes quite a while, I'm sorry! If I were you, I would start by finding the common denominator for all three expressions.

Then, reform them in terms of $a + b + c$, $ab + bc + ca$, and $abc$. You may or may not find the following expressions helpful:
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= (a + b + c)^2 - 2(ab + bc + ac) \\
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 &= (a + b + c)^3 - 3(ab + bc + ac)(a + b + c) + 3abc
\end{align}